# Using SharedPreference to save user details

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I understand that the best way to save values is to use SharedPreferences e.g.

```
SharedPreferences Savesettings = getSharedPreferences("settingFile", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor example = Savesettings.edit();
        example.putString("Name", name)
                .putInt("Age", age)
                .putInt("Score", score)
        example.apply();
```

But what if I want my program to remember a button being disabled or enabled after the user closes and opens the program? i have tried a RegisterOnChangePreferanceListener however i have no luck e.g.

```
SharedPreferences Preferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener Example =
                new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
                    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences preferance, String key) {

                        Name = name;//only an example not the main focus
                        Age = age;
                        Score = score;
                        enableBTN = false; //disables button
                        Name.setEnabled(false); //disables the edit text from further editing
}
                };
        Preferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(Example);
```

Is there a way to do this, both methods do not seem to be working for me.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html or https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save it from within the button's `OnClickListener`. That way, everytime the button is clicked, you are guaranteed that the button's state is saved. `button` is a reference to a `Button` view object

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        Button button = (Button)findViewById("this_button_view_id");
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById("this_edit_text_id");
        SharedPreferences Savesettings = getSharedPreferences("settingFile", MODE_PRIVATE);

        // If the Savesettings shared preferences above contains the "isButtonDisabled" key
        // It means the user clicked and disabled the button before
        // So we use that state instead
        // If it does does not contain that key
        // We set it to true so that the button is not disabled
        // Same for the edit text
        button.setEnabled(Savesettings.contains("isButtonDisabled") ? Savesettings.getBoolean("isButtonDisabled") : true);
        editText.setEnabled(Savesettings.contains("isEditTextDisabled") ? Savesettings.getBoolean("isEditTextDisabled") : true);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // disable the edit text
                editText.setEnabled(false);

                // disable the button
                button.setEnabled(false);

                SharedPreferences.Editor example = Savesettings.edit();

                // Save the button state to the shared preferences retrieved above
                example.putBoolean("isButtonDisabled", true);

                // Save the edit text state to the shared preferences retrieved above
                example.putBoolean("isEditTextDisabled", true);
                example.apply();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: But what if i want to set a different background colour or disable edittext?

Comment: When the button is clicked? I mean you can do any types of logics you want within the `OnClickListener`

Comment: Recreate an activity within a button click does not make sense right?, why would you want to do that anyway? you could close the activity or launch a new one, that makes more sense.  The saving to shared preference is bound between  `Savesettings.edit();` and `example.apply();` don't put any other code within that

Comment: but how would this be done, can i have an example please? lets say i want to disable the Edittext called "EDIT_name" how would i do about doing this? i know its EDIT_name.setEnabled(false); but how can it be implemented?

Comment: i am just giving and example with the recreate();

Comment: Yeah, let's say `editText` is the reference to that `EditText` object, you just call `editText.setEnabled(false);` as the last statement. You know how to get a reference to a view object right?

Comment: sorry im still very new to this, how would you do this?

Comment: yes but if i want this to be saved along side the values how would it be done? when the user closes and opens the app i want the edittext to be disables when the button is clicked.

Comment: So you want when the button is clicked. Both the button and the edit text to be disabled, and you want their states to be saved so when the app is closed and reopened, these two view components will be in the previously saved states?